# Specific shortcuts not working on QT

Tags: c++, qt, shortcut

I have some problems with Qt Shortcuts. I extracted my problem into a simple piece of code I am reporting here. 
In my code, I want my `EmptyMainWindow::onShortcutActivated()` to be executed when I press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  combination on the keyboard.
Here is my main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    EmptyMainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here is my EmptyMainWindow Class

```
#include "emptymainwindow.h"
#include "ui_emptymainwindow.h"
#include <QShortcut>
#include <QDebug>

EmptyMainWindow::EmptyMainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
      QMainWindow(parent),
      ui(new Ui::EmptyMainWindow)
{
      ui->setupUi(this);

      QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut (QKeySequence
                           (Qt::CTRL + Qt::SHIFT + Qt::Key_A  ), this);

      connect (shortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(onShortcutActivated()));
 }



void EmptyMainWindow::onShortcutActivated()
{
    qDebug() << "EmptyMainWindow::onShortcutActivated()";
}
```

Now, my problem is that this code does not work in this way but works properly if the shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, etc.

Do you have any idea on why this is happening?

PS: I am working on Windows 7 with the visual studio compiler

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the underlying OS doesn't hook ctrl+shift+a for its own purposes?

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but how can I see all the shortcuts windows is hooking?

Comment: I don't personally use Windows so I can't give you a definitive answer.  However, [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Text_formatting) does seem to suggest that ctrl+shift+a might be hooked for text editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the reason. Thanks to a software called Windows Hotkey Explorer, that gives all the shortcuts that have been registered to the operating system, I have discovered that another program was kind of reserving this shortcut and, thus, it wasn't passed to my application. Do you have any idea on how is it possible to do that on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  this is an issue with QWERTY and AZERTY keyboard. Because on the both C and B have the same position but not A. Have you try to trigger your shortcut with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> ?